# Background image in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

How to add picture to background by ngOnInit? 
I do not want to use `background: url("link of my image")` in CSS because this increases the load of my site. I want to do this by Angular 2 Typescript

Comment: As far as I know styling done in css is faster then done in js.

Comment: Really? 
My landing load all and after that i see image and login form. I need to load login form and at the same time load the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You think right! It can be done by many ways!

1) By change the style input:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import { DomSanitizer  } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <div [style]="getStyle()">
        I am a div that wants to be styled
      </div>
      <button (click)="showStyle = !showStyle;">Toggle style</button>
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {
  showStyle: false;

  constructor() {
  }

  getStyle() {
    // snip snip -> fetch the url from somewhere
    const profilePicUrl = 'some-remote-server-url.jpg';
    const style = `background-image: url(${profilePicUrl})`;
    // sanitize the style expression
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
  }
}
```

2) By change ngClass:

And in ngOnInit() set your variable that you want

3) By adding directive:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[setBackgroundImage]',
})
export class StyledDirective {
  constructor(public el: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer) {
    // el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement, 'backgroundImage', 'yourImageLink');
  }
}
```

And many other ways in this source for example:
https://juristr.com/blog/2016/01/learning-ng2-dynamic-styles/

Answer (score 3):

In your component.ts, import `DomSanitizer`,

> import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

... delare a variable in your component class, say `backgroundImageStyle` and initialize this variable in `ngOnInit`:

```
backgroundImageStyle: string; 

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

public ngOnInit()
{
    this.backgroundImageStyle = this.getBackgroundImageStyle();
}

private getBackgroundImageStyle()
{
    let backgroundImage = './path/to/your/image';

    // sanitize the style expression
    const style = `background-image: url(${backgroundImage})`;
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
}
```

and in your component html, set the style property of your main container:

```
[style]="backgroundImageStyle"
```