# How to set Angular 4 background image?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying the following lines to set the background image.but it not works. what are the way set background image in constantly in my application.

**app.component.html**

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background' : 'url(./images/trls.jpg)'}">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <alert></alert>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you able to get image:   `style="background:'url(./images/trls.jpg)"`"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background image in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45630957/background-image-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use [`ngStyle`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) to set background for a div

```
<div [ngStyle]="{background-image: 'url(./images/' + trls.img + ')'}"></div>
```

or you can also use built in background style:

```
<div [style.background-image]="'url(/images/' + trls.img + ')'"></div>
```

Comment: You forgot to add Closing curly brace in the first solution. It should be 
<div [ngStyle]="{background: 'url(./images/' + trls.img + ')'}"></div>

Thanks for the hints.

Comment: Updated the answer @BiswajitPanday. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. I have exact same problem but none of the answers here helped in my case.

Comment: @AkshayRaut, where have you kept your images? Could you share the complete path?

Comment: @AkashAgrawal Wouldn't it be better to use `[style.background-image]` to avoid overriding already set css attributes.

Comment: <div [style.background-image]="'url(\'/images/' + trls.img + '\')'"></div>
add inverted comma with escape character \' inside url() to be extra safe of image names having multiple white spaces.

Answer (score 31):

> This works for me:

put this in your markup:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': getUrl()}">
```

then in component:

```
getUrl()
{
  return "url('http://estringsoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/estring-header-lowsat.jpg')";
}
```

Comment: If your url happens to have any spaces in it as mine did, you may also want to do a <your url string>.replace(/\s/g, "%20") as well.

Comment: this doesnt work anymore

Answer (score 9):

Below answer worked for angular 4/5.

In app.component.css

```
.image{
     height:40em; background-size:cover; width:auto;
     background-image:url('copied image address');
     background-position:50% 50%;
   }
```

Also in app.component.html simply add as below

```
<div class="image">
Your content
</div>
```

This way I was able to set background image in Angular 4/5.

Comment: The only code that worked for me in the entire Internet. Thank you a million times!

Comment: This is not Angular, it's just plain HTML and CSS

Comment: I couldn't agree more! I just said the below worked for me in angular :)

Comment: that's not the answer: he's asking how to dynamically change copied image address value via js.

Comment: @SachinHatikankan , this solution won't work for putting image url from api. This is just plain html&&css solution. To write something that puts fetched url to background-image in angular for example, one can use [ngStyle]

Answer (score 6):

If you plan using background images a lot throughout your project you may find it useful to create a really simple custom pipe that will create the url for you.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'asUrl'
})
export class BackgroundUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string): string {
    return `url(./images/${value})`
  }

}
```

Then you can add background images without all the string concatenation.

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ background: trls.img | asUrl }"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**In Html**

```
<div [style.background]="background"></div>
```

**In Typescript**

```
this.background= 
this.sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${this.section.backgroundSrc}) no-repeat`);
```

A working solution.

[What is the recommended way to dynamically set background image in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117989/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-dynamically-set-background-image-in-angular-4)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a custom directive, instead of having a method that will execute in a loop affecting performance.

In my case I would created a BackImgDirective like this:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, Renderer2} from "@angular/core";
@Directive({ selector: '[appBackImg]'})
export class BackImgDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input() appBackImg = ''
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

    ngOnInit() {
     this.setBackImg()
    }

    setBackImg(){
     this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'background-image', 'url(' + this.appBackImg + ')')
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<div [appBackImg]="slide.image"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this one is working for me also for internet explorer:

```
<div class="col imagebox" [ngStyle]="bkUrl"></div>
```

...

```
@Input() background = '571x450img';  
bkUrl = {};   
ngOnInit() {
    this.bkUrl = this.getBkUrl();
  }
getBkUrl() {
    const styles = {
      'background-image': 'url(src/assets/images/' + this.background + '.jpg)'
    };
    console.log(styles);
    return styles;
  }
```

Comment: a path with src can't work in a build, there's no src dir under dist

Comment: netalex, this solution seems to slow down the process. Read about the speed of putting already fetched data and data read from function. Sometimes it is a solution to get data from function, I'm not saying it's bad. But, in some cases putting function in template works slow. In this case, it is better to put this.background in [ngStyle] and write additional styles in css/scss/etc. file, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted a profile picture of size 96x96 with data from api. The following solution worked for me in project **Angular 7**.

.ts:

```
  @Input() profile;
```

.html:

```
 <span class="avatar" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url('+ profile?.public_picture +')'}"></span>
```

.scss:

```
 .avatar {
      border-radius: 100%;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 96px;
      height: 96px;
    }
```

Please note that if you write `background` instead of `'background-image'` in `[ngStyle]`, the styles you write (even in `style` of element) for other background properties like background-position/size, etc. won't work. Because you will already fix it's properties with `background: 'url(+ property +) (no providers for size, position, etc. !)'`. The `[ngStyle]` priority is higher than `style` of element. In `background` here, only url() property will work. Be sure to use `'background-image'` instead of `'background'`in case you want to write more properties to background image.

Answer (score 1):

A very easy solution is to declare the image with a loading class and remove this class when image is loaded. You can then customize the placeholder in CSS, as it should be.

HTML :

```
        <img class="persona-avatar loading" #avatar
             (load)="avatar.classList.remove('loading'); "
             src="/assets/img.png"
             alt=""/>
```

SCSS :

```
        .persona-avatar {
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          &.loading {
            background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...");
            background-size: contain;
          }
        }
```

It is better to use a base64 image to not have the same load problem with the placeholder.