# What is the recommended way to dynamically set background image in Angular 4

Tags: css, angular

Currently I'm setting the image background using inline-style.

```
<div [ngStyle]="{background: 'url(' + section.backgroundSrc + ') no-repeat'}">
```

However, I'm looking for a more cleaner approach...maybe something like dynamically setting the path in the external stylesheet through angular. However, I'm not sure how it can be done.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it thourgh CSS files. However, you can make your current code little less verbose :

```
<div [style.background]="'url(' + section.backgroundSrc + ') no-repeat'"></div>
```

If angular throws security errors, you will have to sanitize too. So you will do something like this:
in HTML file-

```
<div [style.background]="background"></div>
```

in your TS file

```
this.background= 
this.sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${this.section.backgroundSrc}) no-repeat`);
```

Comment: Its giving warning in the browser console `WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value url(./assets/img/section-1-image.png) no-repeat (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Harsha Sampath.
I did:

```
[style.backgroundImage]="'url('+urlToImage+')'"
```

works in Angular 8,
urlToImage is a string property of component, resolved at runtime.

The other settings of background are fixed in css:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center center;
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: I started to use use the same from Angual 7, and it still work in Angular 8.

Answer (score 0):

This code has worked for me.

```
[style.backgroundImage]="'url('+MEDIA_URL +'/dir/'+data.image+')'"
```

MEDIA_URL is the base URL of uploaded location.

Angular CLI: 6.1.3 
Angular: 6.1.2

Answer (score 0):

This is the best and easy wasy to handle

```
[ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' +(user.photo ? user.photo : '')+') no-repeat 0 0 / cover'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Html - `<div [style.background]="background">`

TS - `this.section = 'assets/images/bg/waterfallsvg.svg'; this.background = (url(${this.section}) no-repeat);`