# Change element css property dynamically

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ionic4

I need to dynamically set the background image. Since `ion-content` is an element how can I do that? If it is a css class then I can do like so

`[class]="cssClassName"` and I can change the class name inside the `ts` file. But here how can I do that?

*.ts*

```
ngOnInit() { this.init(); }

init() {
    switch (environment.hotelEnvironment.hotelName) {
      case "com1":
       // has back ground
        break;
      case "com2":
       //no back ground
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
```

.html

```
<ion-content>

</ion-content>
```

*.scss*

```
ion-content {
    --background: url('/assets/img/com/background/background.png') no-repeat 100% 100%;

}
```

Comment: how are you going to trigger your init () function

Comment: It runs here `ngOnInit() {
    this.init();
  }` @DCR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two different css classes with the desired backgrounds. Having a class variable to hold the class name that you switch in your init method and binding it to the ion-content component should do it.

```
<ion-content [ngClass]="hotelBackground">
  ...
</ion-content>

ngOnInit() { this.init(); }
hotelBackground: string;
init() {
    switch (environment.hotelEnvironment.hotelName) {
      case "com1":
       this.hotelBackground = 'com1';
       break;
      case "com2":
       this.hotelBackground = 'com2';
       break;
      default:
    }
  }
```

*.scss*

```
.com1 {background: url('/assets/img/com/background/background.png') no-repeat 100% 100%; } 

.com2{ background: none}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to do the `.scss` part? code for that?

Comment: This is the current code `ion-content {
    --background: url('/assets/img/com/background/background.png') no-repeat 100% 100%;

}`

Comment: .com1 {background: url('/assets/img/com/background/background.png') no-repeat 100% 100%; } .com2{ background: none}

Answer (score 1):

use `[class.<YOUR_CLASS_NAME>] = "<SOME CONDITION>"` See this its answered here

[Angular: conditional class with *ngClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass) for reference

Comment: Then how to handle this? `ion-content {
    --background: url('/assets/img/com/background/background.png') no-repeat 100% 100%;

}`

Comment: with `css` you can't change the background dynamically you have to do it in your `ts` file

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: first get the `image src` dynamically and store it in a local variable and then use that in you html template

Comment: [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117989/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-dynamically-set-background-image-in-angular-4) and do some research before asking a question

Comment: See how I have achieved it in a cleaner way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55996610/1077309

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it like so:

***Note:*** Very important part here is this `ion-content.background-image`

*.scss*

```
ion-content.background-image {
    --background: url('/assets/img/com/background/background.png') no-repeat 100% 100%;       
}
```

*.ts*

```
ngOnInit() { this.init(); }

init() {
    switch (environment.hotelEnvironment.hotelName) {
      case "com1":
        this.cssClassName = "";
        break;
      case "com2":
        this.cssClassName = "background-image";
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
```

*.html*

```
 <ion-content [ngClass]="cssClassName">

    </ion-content>
```

Answer (score -1):

something like this might work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(".content1").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.content1.active {
  background-image: url('../images/light.png');
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Clicky</button>
<div class="content1"> Hello </div>
```

Comment: I'm not using `jQuery` at all. This is `Angular only` app.