# how to properly escape ngstyle background-image

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I can't figure out how to escape this:

```
<div *ngFor="let formulario of formularios" [ngStyle]="{‘background-image’ : 'url(' + imagenPath + formulario[" imagen "] + ')'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proper binding would be

```
<div
  [style.background]="'url(' + path + ')'">
</div>
```

where path is correct image path.

A simple StackBlitz with working example -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wunc7a

Note: The question is duplicate -> [How to set Angular 4 background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45632663/how-to-set-angular-4-background-image)

Comment: This is more about how to escape the url between the rest of elements, so I don't consider it duplicate. Anyways, your answer helped fix it.