# Trying to add a background image on a webpage using the angular framework

Tags: html, css, angular

So I'm setting up my own webpage (it isn't live yet) and am having trouble adding a background image. I've scoured the web and this website in particular finding possible solutions to my issue, but with no prevail. I understand how to add a background image not using the angular framework, but rather through a simple html page where everything is kept in one html file. However, when I try it in the `angular` framework it all falls apart. (meaning either the image won't show or it does and simply does not conform to the styles I set for the image)

Before I tried anything I went into my `angular.json` file and changed the “`assets`” field to the following:
            "assets": [
                      "src/favicon.ico",
                      "src/assets",
                      "src/assets/images" ->I added this so angular 
                 knows where to find the image
                 ],

First approach:(this is the approach that actually works in my simple one page HTML file)
In the HTML file:

```
   <div class="bgimg-1">*usually i'd put my navbar here*</div>
```

In the `CSS` file:

```
        .bgimg-1 {
            background-image: url("me_copy.jpg");
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            opacity: 0.8;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
          }
```

Second approach:

To make sure that I have the correct path I even tried to just put an image up on the webpage not caring about styles or anything. The path I have worked to display the image. Then, when I went to style it, the image disobeyed all my style constraints and simply extended past both the right and bottom sides of my webpage. Again, I'v tried it on my other webpage, using the same image, that utilizes just one html doc for everything and it worked. It seems that when there are multiple files at play (not everything is in one place) it all falls apart.

To give you a visual of my expectations [visit](https://devoncrawford.io/)
My expectations are for the webpage to:

1. display a background image that is fit to the screen such as in the first approach I posted
2. (this isn't as pressing of an issue I’m just boggled that I couldn’t figure this out) for any other non-background images to be fit to the size of the webpage and not overflow.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please refer to this post. this will help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45632663/how-to-set-angular-4-background-image

Comment: Thank you for that, but I have already seen that. Unfortunately that didn't work and I put it under my second approach but it got deleted for whatever reason so it never posted.