# why is my host ip changed in 'localhost' when using url() in css background property

Tags: html, css, angular, google-app-engine

I'm checking my website on my old Ipad via my MacBook.

I'm using an api call that's gives me back a URL of the background image.

All the others images displays fine on my computer and Ipad somehow when trying to add the value `url('http://192.168.***.*:8080/my_images/img.jpg')` to my `background` css propety it converts it to `url('http://localhost:8080/my_images/img.jpg')` which of course doesn't work.

I've setted host to this ip when using `ng serve` also add this tag `--address=192.168.***.*` to my app engine server (using eclipse). Is it a normal behaviour? is there any ways to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45632663/how-to-set-angular-4-background-image#answer-56846713) after noticing I got XSS/attack warning in my console.

the solution was to use `DOMSanitizer` and unsanitize the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Example of a angular project with SCSS style.

In index.html file:

```
<base href="/">
```

In variables.scss file:

```
$base-url: '';
```

In override.scss file:

```
@import "./variables.scss";

/deep/ #dvLoading {
    ...
    background: url($base-url+"/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif") no-repeat center #fff;
    ...
}
```