# Dynamic image loading in div

Tags: angular, angular8

Now I am doing an angular 8 project. I need to load an image dynamically, that came from the back end. I want this image load in a particular div section. I tried this. but not working. Anybody help?

```
 <div class="col-md-5 box mt-4" style="background-image: url({{url}}/SupportingFiles/profile/{{institution_folder_name}}/idcards/front.jpg);">
```

Comment: This is my code    

<div class="col-md-5 box mt-4" style="background-image: url({{url}}/SupportingFiles/profile/{{institution_folder_name}}/idcards/front.jpg);">

Comment: why don't you just put and `img` inside `div`, did you tried that ?

Comment: Use `ngStyle` to set the background. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45632663/how-to-set-angular-4-background-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `height` and `width` of the background image to display it properly if you are using `background-image`. Otherwise it won't work.

```
 <div class="col-md-5 box mt-4" style="background-image: url({{url}}/SupportingFiles/profile/{{institution_folder_name}}/idcards/front.jpg); height: xxpx; width:xxpx">
```

Better add a class.

Comment: When I am using the above code, got a warning message like this

core.js:6677 WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value background-image: url(https://qa.embase.in/SupportingFiles/profile/qa/idcards/front.jpg); height: 950px; width:850px (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).

Comment: How can I set the dynamic URL into class?

Comment: Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6OP-lPJxgs&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwhBRAgFinJR8KHIrCdTkZcZ&index=7

Comment: And if possible please create a stackblitz example