# Angular 4 background-image not loading

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, background-image

Okay, I have looked through all of stack to figure out how to fix this problem.

So my problem is that I want to add a background image to my header tag. The background image doesnt not load. It doesnt appear at all.

So far I've tried using the module DomSanitizer. This is in my header.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer, SafeStyle} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-header',
    templateUrl: './header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent {
backgroundImageStyle: SafeStyle;

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

    public ngOnInit()
    {
        this.backgroundImageStyle = this.getBackgroundImageStyle();
    }

    private getBackgroundImageStyle()
    {
        let backgroundImage = '../img/header_bg.png';

        // sanitize the style expression
        const style = `background-image: url(${backgroundImage})`;
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
    }
}
```

I got this from [Background image in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45630957/background-image-in-angular-2)

I've even tried

```
<div [style.background-image]="'url(../img/' + header.png + ')'></div>
```

Is there something I'm missing to load a background image using css? 
I just need a simple way use this

That is in my header.component.css

```
header.background {
    width:100%; 
    float:left; 
    margin:0px; 
    padding:0px; 
    background:url(../img/header_bg.png) repeat #FFFFFF; 
    display:block; 
    z-index:999999;
}
```

This is in my header.component.html

```
<header class="background">
    <img alt="logo" src="../img/clothesline.png" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" class="logo">
</header>
```

Like am I missing a dependency that loads background images?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

`<header [ngStyle]="{'background':  'url(../img/header_bg.png) repeat #fff'}">`

Instead of externally referencing try inline.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Does it have anything to do with webpack? cause I know that for when I was using an img tag I had to install file-loader and then my image worked for it. This one is different cause I'm now using background-image using css

Comment: Let do one thing, `<header style="background:  url(../img/header_bg.png) repeat #fff'">` . Using pure `HTML` inline `CSS` technique to check whether the image is loading or not.

Comment: Still not appearing. It's so strange. I'm now doing everything in the app.component.html to make it easier, but still nothing